# Android XML display choices conditionally based on Spinner value

Tags: android, conditional-statements, spinner

I am making a sports related app and am caught up early.

On my first activity the layout is a spinner, whose value can be any sport (NHL, MLB, NFL).

When a sport is selected I want, on the same page right below the spinner, a date picker to come up, DD/MM/YYYY.

I have no problem there except when NFL is selected: instead of a date picker, I want another spinner to appear with the values 1-16 (the weeks throughout the season) as I will need this info rather than the date to do what I want with NFL.

I have strings.mxl already set up with the spinner values and adding in the date picker is easy but how do i get either one to come up conditionally based on the first spinner value?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
mSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new onItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
     int position, long arg3) {
     //position shows the item clicked
     //choose your action here
     //if(position=="position of NFL"){
           //do this
       }
});
```

Comment: Im getting an error trying to use setOnItemClickListener... eclipse keeps telling me to use setOnclicklistener

Comment: i found elsewhere an answer to use onItemSelected for spinners as onItem is for listviews and onItem is specifially for spinners. i appreciate your fast answering

Comment: yes my mistake ,it is not for spinners though they extend AdapterView.and yes you are right you have to use onItemSelected.